# MindMaster mind-mapping tool does not show cloud documents

Tags: chromium, qt

MindMaster, an app for creating mind-maps, does not show cloud documents. Here is the output from running the app from the command line:

```
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
QPixmap::scaled: Pixmap is a null pixmap
[1006/191117.068229:WARNING:stack_trace_posix.cc(648)] Failed to open file: /memfd:/.glXXXXXX (deleted)
  Error: No such file or directory
[1006/191117.070038:ERROR:data_pack.cc(209)] Bad data pack version: got 5, expected 4
[1006/191117.070342:ERROR:resource_bundle_qt.cpp(123)] failed to load locale.pak
[1006/191117.110787:ERROR:data_pack.cc(209)] Bad data pack version: got 5, expected 4
[1006/191117.111244:ERROR:resource_bundle_qt.cpp(123)] failed to load locale.pak
[46708:46748:1006/191117.161890:ERROR:nss_util.cc(750)] After loading Root Certs, loaded==false: NSS error code: -8018
[1:1:1006/191117.165571:ERROR:data_pack.cc(209)] Bad data pack version: got 5, expected 4
Received signal 11 SEGV_MAPERR 000000000000
#0 0x7f7f524660a5 <unknown>
#1 0x7f7f511a7141 <unknown>
#2 0x7f7f5246643d <unknown>
#3 0x7f7f4e5d93c0 <unknown>
#4 0x7f7f52db9f70 <unknown>
#5 0x7f7f52db4248 <unknown>
#6 0x7f7f52db1b3d <unknown>
#7 0x7f7f511c430b <unknown>
#8 0x7f7f534d9be4 <unknown>
#9 0x7f7f535db716 <unknown>
#10 0x7f7f537f7da2 <unknown>
#11 0x7f7f537881c2 <unknown>
#12 0x7f7f5379f47d <unknown>
#13 0x7f7f551251a3 <unknown>
#14 0x7f7f5377cb21 <unknown>
#15 0x7f7f5377cc11 <unknown>
#16 0x7f7f5511b047 <unknown>
#17 0x7f7f551255e0 <unknown>
#18 0x7f7f55127fe2 <unknown>
#19 0x7f7f54d73c25 <unknown>
#20 0x7f7f51bf1503 <unknown>
#21 0x7f7f51c79527 <unknown>
#22 0x7f7f51c79cc7 <unknown>
#23 0x3f30fe70463d <unknown>
  r8: 00007ffd10879710  r9: 0000000000000000 r10: 0000000000000000 r11: 00007ffd108796dc
 r12: 00007ffd10879710 r13: 00007ffd10879920 r14: 0000000000004e8b r15: 0000000000000000
  di: 0000000000000000  si: 0000000000004e8b  bp: 0000000000000000  bx: 000000000182d840
  dx: 00007ffd10879710  ax: 00007f7f56d78468  cx: 0000000000004e8b  sp: 00007ffd10879510
  ip: 00007f7f52db9f70 efl: 0000000000010202 cgf: 002b000000000033 erf: 0000000000000004
 trp: 000000000000000e msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.
```

I know that this is a proprietary software, but maybe it is the issue from some packanges missing. I am using linux mint 20, with xfce DE.